# How use MAC parameter to open 80 port for specific machines in iptables on OpenWRT router

Tags: configuration, port, iptables, openwrt

Now I use `OpenWRT 17.04` firmware for my router, but I need to configure access to my router and open `80` port for specific machines when I add  a rule like

```
WAN='eth0.2
iptables -A input_rule -i $WAN -p tcp --dport 80  -m mac --mac-source XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -j ACCEPT`
```

where `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` - the specific machine which tries to get access, but no results. What happens? Why doesn't it work?

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There no ways to specify MAC address of a machine. You should use IP address instead of.